# Geocoding with noisy addresses

Tags: geocoding

I have addresses that are somewhat noisy since they have been entered by humans. What this basically means is that in most cases the addresses make perfect sense, but in other cases it can something such as `Right door on 2nd floor, MegaMall, 2100, Copenhagen.`

Is there any service that allows for geocoding and can give some kind of score if they are able to geocode the address or not? :) Afraid of getting some coordinates that just simply does not make any sense.

Comment: Are all these locations in one particular city, or multiple or what?

Comment: Fuzzy Geocoding example  https://developer.tomtom.com/blog/decoded/understanding-fuzzy-search

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this

https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/OtherGeocoders/

It lists a bunch of geocoders for US and non-US addresses.  It's provided by Texas A&M and most of the services listed are free although many have record limits per day.

Answer (score 0):

The [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro) from google might be something for you. it basically uses the same way of searching as typing stuff into Google Maps. Not perfect but quite decent and precise when it gets a result.

Comment: not sure that will allow you to store the LAT/LON results once geocoded, as with most of the other Google Maps API terms

Answer (score 0):

[YAddress](https://www.yaddress.net) (made by the company I work for) does address validation and correction in one pass with geocoding. For every address, you get an error code that tells you if the address was correct or not, and if not, what the problem was.

In the process of correcting the address, all typos, misspellings and other human issues are taken care of. It also resolves alternative names, alternative spellings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very interesting task. We, at [Geoapify](https://www.geoapify.com), trying to clean up an address before geocoding it and do it very successfully for some cases. But as you gave only one address sample and it's difficult to say if it will solve your task. Try to play around with the [Playground](https://apidocs.geoapify.com/playground/geocoding) and test.
Otherwise, if you know the address structure, this could help as well.